# How many elements associated (in the same conjugacy class) with a $\sigma \in S_{3n}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $\sigma = (123)...(3n-2, 3n-1, 3n) \in S_{3n}$

The question is how many elements associated (in the same conjugacy class) with a $\sigma \in S_{3n}$

As I understood we can see how transposition affects our permutation, and then say that every permutation we want to find is product of transpositions.

It worked for $\sigma'=(12...k)$, but I don't know what else I can do here.

Comment: This is exactly the same as your deleted question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043120/how-many-elements-associated-with-a-sigma-in-s-3n.

Comment: Yes, I just fixed some formulations.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fact that two elements in a symmetric group are in the same conjugacy class **if and only if** they have the same cycle structure.

So all you have to do is compute how many elements of the form $(***)(***)\dots(***)$ the group $S_{3n}$ contains.

This can be done with purely combinatorial methods: let $N$ be this number, then

$$ N = 2^{n}*\frac{1}{n!}{3n \choose 3}{{3n-3}\choose 3}\dots {6 \choose 3}{3 \choose 3} = \frac{2^n}{n!} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} {{3n-3i}\choose 3}$$

where we multiply by $2$ each factor because given a fixed set of three elements there are two possible distinct cycles that can occur (namely $(123)$ and $(132)$), and we divide by $n!$ since disjoint cycles commute and can be written in any order (namely $(123)(456)=(456)(123)$ )

(thinking about it, there are probably better formulas that use multinomial coefficients: suggestions welcome!)

Comment: Thank you! But can you explain first statement about elements from the same class? May be some references to understand this. I'll be very grateful!

Comment: Well, it would be harder to find a group theory book that does NOT contain this result! I found this one, but there are hundreds: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Classes_of_Symmetric_Group